Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics Chapter 1 Problem 83.
Question:

The Stirling numbers of the first kind denoted by $s(r,n)$ is defined as the number of ways to distribute $r$ objects into $n$ circles such that no circle is empty. These numbers can occur as coefficients of $x^n$ in the expansion of $$x(x+1)(x+2) \dotsb (x+r-1)$$ For instance, when $r=3$, $$\begin{align*} x(x+1)(x+2) &= 2x+3x^2 + x^3 \\
&=s(3,1)x + s(3,2)x^2 + s(3,3)x^3 \end{align*}$$ and when $r=5$
$$\begin{align*} 
 & x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4) \\
\text{} &= 24x + 50x^2 + 35x^3 + 10x^4 + x^5 \\
&= s(5,1)x + s(5,2)x^2 + s(5,3)x^3 + s(5,4)x^4 + s(5,5)x^5 \end{align*}$$
Show that
$$x(x+1)(x+2) \dotsb (x+r-1) = \sum_{n=0}^r s(r,n)x^n$$

I know that we need to proceed by induction. The case $r=1$ is trivial. I assume that this holds for $r=k$, which means that $x(x+1)(x+2) \dotsb (x+k-1) = \sum_{n=0}^k s(k,n)x^n$. Unfortunately, I do not know how to verify the case $r=k+1$. I am stuck here: $x(x+1)(x+2) \dotsb (x+k-1)(x+k) = (x+k)\sum_{n=0}^n s(r,k)x^n$

I post two questions and I answered both myself XD. Doing a favour for the forums hahahah

Your question is a duplicate of this older one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135972/rising-factorial-stirling-numbers-from-the-recurrence

That is true, but I think this question is still relevant because on the older version it uses the sum and work to the sequence of products. In my solution, I work from the sequence of products to the summation.

We will proceed by induction. The case $r=1$ is trivial. Assume this holds for case $r= k$. Thus:
$$\begin{align*}
    x(x+1)(x+2) \dotsb (x+k-1) = \sum_{n=0}^k s(k,n) x^n = s(k,0)x^0 + s(k,1)x^1 + \dots + s(k,k)x^k
\end{align*}$$
Now we check for $r=k+1$. Recall this formula $$\begin{align} s(k+1,n) = s(k,n-1) + ks(k,n)  \end{align}$$ Now we can solve the problem:
$$\begin{align*}
    &x(x+1)(x+2)\dotsb(x+k-1)(x+(k+1)-1) \\
    &= x(x+1)(x+2) \dotsb (x+k-1)(x+k) \\ 
    &= \sum_{n=0}^k s(k,n)x^n(x+k) \\
    &= \sum_{n=0}^k x^{n+1}s(k,n) + \sum_{n=0}^k kx^ns(k,n) \\
    &= \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} x^n s(k,n-1) + \sum_{n=1}^k kx^ns(k,n) \\
    &= x^{k+1} + \sum_{n=1}^k x^ns(k,n-1) + \sum_{n=1}^k kx^ns(k,n) \\
    &= x^{k+1} + \sum_{n=1}^k x^ns(k,n-1) + kx^ns(k,n) \\
    &= x^{k+1} + \sum_{n=1}^k x^n\left(s(k,n-1) + ks(k,n)\right) \\
    &= \sum_{n=1}^k x^ns(k+1,n) + x^{k+1} \\
    &= \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} x^ns(k+1,n) \hspace{0.1in} \blacksquare
\end{align*}$$
